# Appending and Looping in Stata - Is it possible to see which file generated the error message

Tags: append, stata

This is a general question for Stata's `append` command. Is there a way to know which file messed up the `append` loop due to a variable mismatch?

For example, if I receive this following error message am I able to tell which file using file the loop is on? Below is the code and error message.

```
set more off
local files : dir "$analysis/clean_stata" files "*.dta"

    foreach file in `files' {
    append using `files'

    }
```

Error message:

```
variable company_number is str101 in master but double in using data
You could specify append's force option to ignore this string/numeric mismatch.  The using variable would then be treated as if it contained "".
```

Comment: You can use `set trace on` to see the underlying code that is being executed. This will show you exactly where the error occurs.

Comment: Note that you don't need a loop in principle as `append` will accept multiple files. But you do need a loop for this problem. As @braces points out, the syntax is confused here as between `file` and `files`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could add a `display` command:

```
set more off
local files : dir "$analysis/clean_stata" files "*.dta"

    foreach file in `files' {
        display "Trying to append `file'" // I added code here!
        append using `file' // I also put "file" instead of "files" as I think it's what you meant

    }
```

This should allow you to see which file caused the issue.

Comment: Note also that if the file name contains spaces you need also `""` around the name.